# How to submit a form if reCaptcha success

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Greeting All,

Im not sure either this is a right way to do it. Assume had a form here and if my recaptcha return success how can I sent the action to `login.php`? else if return false display an error message.

My Form

```html
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <form id="login-form" class="login-form" method="POST" action="login.php">

    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
    <button id="login-button" name="login-submit">login</button>

  </form>   
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</div>
```

php reCaptcha

```js
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $secretKey = "my_secret_key";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //optional

        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response);
        if ($response->success)
            // echo "Success";
      // if success form submit to login.php
        else
            // echo "Failed";
      // return error message
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u have little logical issue here, you are already doing everything right, u just need to add your login functions right here in captcha checking script or vice versa.
that means you can submit form directly to login.php and there check if recatcha is right, if yes proceed to login functions, if not return error.
u just need little changes to your existing code.

HTML

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <form id="login-form" class="login-form" method="POST" action="login.php">    
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
    <button id="login-button" name="login-submit">login</button>    
  </form>   
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</div>
```

LOGIN.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password ']; //password for login check
        //check recaptcha
        $secretKey = "my_secret_key";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //optional    
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response);
        if ($response->success){
            // echo "Success";
            // IF SUCCESS PROCEED WITH YOUR LOGIN CHECKING FUCTIONS HERE
        }else{
            // echo "Failed";
            // RETURN ERROR MESSAGE
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: omg..I cant believe I made a silly mistake here. U right this thing made me confuse. Thank you for alerting me here.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use the JS version of reCaptcha then add this script on reCaptcha success to submit the form

`document.getElementById("login-form").submit();`

Look for JS API
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display